# Methods In Java - Void

Tags: java, methods

I am currently learning about methods and using methods. It sometimes confuses my mind when deciding what to put inside the parameters. I have some code where I created three methods and all correspond. What I must do for this program is to display some services and prices and ask the user if he/she would like it. If they say yes, the prices add up until the end of the array. The part I am having trouble with is how to take in the price from main in my third method. I know that I should use a void method because I am not returning anything, just printing out the prices to the user. 
Heres my piece of code for this program:

```
static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("What automobile make do you own?");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    String name = keyboard.nextLine();
    make(name);

    double price = carMaintenance(name);
    finalPrice(price);

}

// First Method
public static void make(String name) {
    System.out.println("Hello! We will be happy to service your " + name
            + " automobile today!");
}

// Second Method
public static double carMaintenance(String name) {
    String[] services = { "Oil Change", "Tire Rotation", "Air Filter",
            "Check Fluids" };
    double[] prices = { 39.99, 49.99, 19.99, 10.99 };
    double Total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < services.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Do you want a " + services[i] + " for your "
                + name + " " + prices[i] + "? (y/n)");
        String answer;
        answer = keyboard.nextLine();
        if (answer.equals("y"))
        {
            Total = Total + prices[i];
        }
// Third method
    public static void finalPrice ( ? )
```

---

Specifically this the part I am having trouble with:

// Third method
        public static void finalPrice (double price )

The problem is finalPrice is an invalid type for the variabl which is pretty confusing about.

Comment: What makes it different from `carMaintenance`/`make`? You're passing a value there as well..

Answer (score 2):

You have to change `finalPrice()` to accept a `double` parameter:

```
public static void finalPrice(double price) { ... }
```

And pass the value returned by `carMaintenance()` to `finalPrice()`:

```
double price = carMaintenance(name);
finalPrice(price);
```

Note I am assuming you just forgot to paste the rest of the `carMaintenance()` method. In the end, of course, it should have the `return Total` statement.

Comment: Oh I see, but why does it say void is an invalid data type for finalPrice?

Comment: @Chang852 Did you declare `finalPrice` as a method (`public static void finalPrice(double price) { // code here }`) or as a variable (`public static void finalPrice;`)?

Comment: I declared it as a method.

Comment: @Chang852 Please update your question with exactly the same code you have now.

Comment: @Chang852 You need to paste the code for the `finalPrice()` method. And the rest of the code for `carMaintenance()` would also be good.

Answer (score 0):

Your second method is lacking a return statement. You can return the total to main and then send it to your third method, as such:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("What automobile make do you own?");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    String name = keyboard.nextLine();
    make(name);

    double finalPrice = carMaintenance(name);
    printFinalPrice(finalPrice);
}

//first method code here

public static double carMaintenance(String name) {
    //second method code here, plus:
    return total;
}

// Third method
public static void printFinalPrice(double finalprice) {
    System.out.println("Your final price is " + finalprice);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass double from carMaintance to finalPrice

```
double finalPriceDbl = carMaintenance(name);
finalprice(finalPriceDbl);
```

and accept double as parameter in finalPrice

```
public static void finalPrice ( double finalPrice );
```

also you should return value from carMaintenance with return statemenet

```
return Total;
```